# undefined reference to template class member

Tags: c++

I am getting an undefined reference to my Pairwise class after I attempt to run it with sample input. My Pairwise class was made in a headerfile, and I made a main function to pass in key and value as strings to format them as I'd like.

My expected output:

```
key:value
```

My headerfile:

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
using std::ostream; using std::cout; using std::endl;
#include<string>
using std::string;
#include<sstream>
using std::ostringstream;

template<typename K, typename V> 
   struct Pairwise { 
   K first; 
   V second; 
   Pairwise() = default; 
   Pairwise(K,V); 
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Pairwise &p){
        out << p.first << ":" << p.second;
        return out;
    }
   };
```

My main function:

```
#include "file.h"

#include<iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;
#include<sstream>
using std::ostringstream;
#include<string>
using std::string;

int main()
{
    Pairwise<string,string> p("key", "value");

    ostringstream oss;
    oss<<p;
    string example = oss.str();
    cout << example << endl;
}
```

The error that I am getting:

```
/tmp/ccfv4iaY.o: In function `main':
main_program.cpp:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `Pairwise<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Pairwise(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You've declared a `Pairwise` constructor taking two parameters, but you haven't actually implemented it. You are nevertheless trying to use it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah I see what you mean! How could I implement Pairwise constructor to print out key:value if you don't mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template contains a declaration for `Pairwise(K,V);`, but it is never defined / implemented anywhere.

You need to add the definition in the same (or another) header file. To verify, replace the `;` by `{}`, and the linker error should be gone: `Pairwise(K,V) {}` (it won't work but it will compile and link fine).